# Is there a limit to the number of websites you can claim in Facebook Insights?

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights, limits

We have a use-case where we need to claim potentially hundreds of subdomains of a website which we own in order to show our customers Facebook Insights data for just their content.  Does anyone know if there a limit to the number of domains/sub-domains that you can claim in Facebook insights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a limit, but it certainly has to be higher than a few hundred. Facebook designed some of their API so companies like ad agencies could provide social campaigns for their clients. For example, Buddy Media had hundreds if not thousands of clients for their products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Brent.  My worry is that companies like BuddyMedia, have a "special" relationship with Facebook. I could be wrong, but, I would hate to get going and hit some invisible ceiling.  If anyone knows for sure, one way or the other, I'd love to know.

Comment: I've been involved in a few beta programs with Facebook and the only "special" things we had was early access to new API calls. At one point I had almost 200 applications (100 prod, 100 dev), all linked to websites. Zynga is probably the only company that has gotten special treatment. I can tell you Facebook's insights dashboard interface doesn't scale well. So you may want to split sites across multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks again, Brent. In my case I will have only one application but linked to lots of subdomains vs. lots of applications linked to one website each.  We are doing this because we want to be able to show customers aggregate statistics and the only way this seems possible is at the domain/subdomain (or application) level. So, our approach is to split up our one site into one subdomain per customer and then "claim" those subdomains in Facebook Insights. So, I'm asking about the limit around claiming subdomains not creating applications.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented, a lot of the workings of facebook insight seems obscured and hidden for some reason. Many people still don't know about the insight for domains so well done for getting this far.

There shouldn't be a limit, after all claiming your domain is just creating a link is the same as any other transaction in the open graph.